# MutableStateOf of mutableList not updating

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, mutablelist, mutablestateof

Why my mutableStateOf of mutableList not updating?

```
    val checkedList by remember {
        mutableStateOf(MutableList(list.size) { false })
```

Comment: How do you modify contents? Do you modify the list directly? If yes, you should instead create a new list and assign it to the state.

Comment: Not directly, list.size changing.

Comment: That cannot work because your previous value will be the same list instance, so no changes can be detected by the state. Basically, never use anything mutable as the type of your State.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use
`val checkedList by remember { mutableStateListOf<Boolean> { false })`.
This helps you better with update operations with view model flows and better code readability
Source with example : https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableStateListOf()